# implement torque control on a robot with some joints supporting torque control while others only supporting velocity control

Tags: control

I have a robot, some joints of which supports torque control,while the rest only supports velocity control. What should I do to implement torque control on the whole system?

Comment: This is a tricky question, In the velocity control do you have access to current readings? if so you could estimate the torque with that and then do a torque control in the velocity control joints.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Xuanchen Zhang, but I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. Think about how you can break your big question down into smaller, *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, including details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.